# Кодировка GD:Simple

Tags: кодировка, perl

Как установить кодировку, чтобы выводились русские буквы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно применить шрифт, поддерживающий utf8, например:

```
use GD::Simple;
use utf8;

my $s = "текст";
my $img = GD::Simple->new(400,250);
$img->moveTo(10,180);

$img->font("Alef:italic");

$img->string($s);
print $img->png;
```

естественно шрифт должен быть в ОС

Comment: Спасибо, я так и решил пару часов назад)